# Perform several t.tests simultaneously on tidy data in R

Tags: r, statistics, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
id  samediff  factor  value
1   S         give    3
1   S         impact  4
2   S         give    2
2   S         impact  5   
3   D         give    1
3   D         impact  4
4   D         give    3
4   D         impact  5
```

I would like to perform several t.tests to compare the means for each factor in the S (samediff) condition to the means for that same factor in the D (samediff) condition.

I know I could do this in the following way:

```
dfgive<-filter(df, factor == "give")
t.test(value~samediff, dfgive)

dfimpact<-filter(df, factor == "impact")
t.test(value~samediff, dfimpact)
```

Is there a way to perform several t.tests in fewer lines? In the actual dataset, there are several more factors than are included here. I would like to be able to conduct all the t.tests necessary without creating separate dataframes in the same way I've shown above.

Comment: Why are you not using ANOVA or a mixed-effect linear model if you have various (nested) strata/groups? Multiple individual *t*-tests will not allow you to properly control for the overall Type I error rate. That's the whole multiple testing correction business and why individual hypothesis tests on a subset of your data are *never* a good idea.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - absolutely. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I will definitely use ANOVA and am not familiar with a mixed-effect linear model. Honestly, t.tests just seemed easiest as a starting point. Any resources you'd recommend that elaborate on the issues you highlighted? Also, I am aware of multiple testing as an issue but do not currently know how to correct for it.

Comment: You correct for multiple testing with e.g. a post-hoc test after an ANOVA. Take a look at `?TukeyHSD`. Alternatively you can also use `pairwise.t.test` which automatically corrects for multiple comparisons. You can find many tutorials on mixed-effect linear modelling using e.g. the `lme4` package on the web. Some of the `lme4` authors are also very active on SO, so here (and Cross Validated) are good starting points to search for practical examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can group by 'factor' and `summarise` the output of `t.test` in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
        group_by(factor) %>% 
        summarise(ttest = list(t.test(value ~ samediff)))

out
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  factor ttest      
#  <chr>  <list>     
#1 give   <S3: htest>
#2 impact <S3: htest>
```

The output is stored in a `list` column which can be extracted with `$` or `[[`

```
identical(out$ttest[[1]], t.test(value ~ samediff, dfgive))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This does not seem to yield the same t.test output as in the example I gave. How do I see information like the p-values and means for each group, as is shown automatically when typically conducting a t.test?

Comment: @melbez It is stored as a `list` column.  You can check the output of the `list` with `out$ttest` and extract individual components `out$ttest[[1]]`

Comment: Is there a way for the factor name to come up when looking at out$ttest? It currently just gives numbers like [[1]] instead of the factor names.

Comment: @melbez  You can just name the `out$ttest` with `out$factor`  Here, it is just storing it in a data.frame so that you can look at the rows if you wanted.  But, if you need it in a separate object `lst <- out$ttest; names(lst) <- out$factor`

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 10):

To augment existing answers, you can use `broom::tidy` to tidy the output from the `t.test`, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%
  summarise(ttest = list(t.test(value ~ samediff))) %>%
  mutate(ttest = map(ttest, tidy)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(factor, estimate, estimate1, estimate2, p.value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   factor estimate estimate1 estimate2 p.value
#   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 give       -0.5       2         2.5   0.712
# 2 impact      0         4.5       4.5   1
```

Here's a base-R approach:

```
results <- lapply(split(df, df$factor), function(X) {
  out <- t.test(value ~ samediff, X)
  data.frame(diff = out$statistic,
             mean1 = out$estimate[1],
             mean2 = out$estimate[2],
             pval = out$p.value)
})
do.call(rbind, results)
#              diff mean1 mean2      pval
# give   -0.4472136   2.0   2.5 0.7117228
# impact  0.0000000   4.5   4.5 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 6):

We can split the data by `factor` and apply `t.test` one by one. The final output is a list. We can access the result by `lst$give` or `lst$impact`.

```
library(tidyverse)

lst <- df %>%
  split(.$factor) %>%
  map(~t.test(value ~ samediff, .x))
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "id  samediff  factor  value
1   S         give    3
1   S         impact  4
2   S         give    2
2   S         impact  5   
3   D         give    1
3   D         impact  4
4   D         give    3
4   D         impact  5 ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what each line is doing (specifically split and map)?

Comment: `split` splits the data frame by the `factor` column to create a list with individual data frames. `map` apply the `t.test` function to each individual data frames.

Comment: Where is there a "." before .$factor in line 2 and .x in line 3?

Comment: `.` in the `split` means the object before the pipe operator, which is the data frame `df`. `.x` in the `map` function means the element in the list.